# How to convert a CSV file to XML with powershell?

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, csv, .net-core

Is `Convert-To-Xml` available in dotnet, or powershell core?

```
Convert-To-Xml : The term 'Convert-To-Xml' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:32
+ Import-Csv "./Processes.csv" | Convert-To-Xml
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Convert-To-Xml:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm trying the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-xml?view=powershell-6) example: `Import-Csv "./Processes.csv" | Convert-To-Xml`

Comment: Convert-ToXml (omitting the hyphen between To and Xml) is available in PowerShell 4.0

Comment: @mjsqu - on my system it's `ConvertTo-Xml` ... [*grin*]

Comment: One of the standard reasons for closing a question is "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error", so please consider deleting your question.